# Fullcalendar eventDrop on confirm looks like revert

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, save, fullcalendar, confirm

When i am using eventDrop with a confirm box before processing the drop data it looks like the event is reverting to its original location.
When i click on Oke the event is dropped correctly.
Does anyone has got a solution for this?

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
    revertFunc();
    } else {
    savedrop(event.id,event.start,event.end);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an solution for this.
At the beginning of the Eventdrop and/or Eventresize i placed the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
```

I can than show the confirm and ajax call on confirm to save this with php.
Also if this is not confirmed i can still use revertFunc.